# Centering Bandcamp Embed HTML5, CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble centering the embedded bandcamp player on my webpage. Here's what I'm trying;

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe style="margin:0 auto" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=2135428685/size=large/bgcol=ffffff/linkcol=0687f5/tracklist=false/artwork=small/transparent=true/" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

I've tried a few different style parameters (`display:block`, `auto`, etc.), and had no luck. The player is locked to the left side of the div.

This is not an issue with the YouTube or Soundcloud embedded players. I use the same code as above, but leave out the `style=""` section.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link you could share to see it?, also is `embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3` the size you expect it to be?

Comment: It isn't live yet. I added a screenshot to the post. 4:3 seems to be an alright size, although I assume I'd be fiddling with that once the player is centered.

Comment: That surrounding div is 100% width then? Sounds like a long shot but have you tried `text-align: center;` on it?

Comment: Yes I have. No dice.

The container is from bootstrap.min, I think it changes width based on screen size.